# Convert time to categorical variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, datetime

```
df 
Time      | Day_of_the_Week 
16:24:18  | Sat
17:00:01  | Sun
03:48:12  | Mon
```

Expected Output:

```
df 
Time      | Day_of_the_Week | Time_Category 
16:24:18  | Sat             |    Afternoon
17:00:01  | Sun             |    Evening
03:48:12  | Mon             |    Midnight
```

df['Time'][1] returns a "datetime.time"

The following code returns an invalid syntax.

```
for a in df:
    if df['Time'] > 17:00:00:
         df['Time_Category'] == 'Evening'
    elif df['Time'] > '12:00:00':
         df['Time_Category'] == 'Afternoon'
    elif df['Time'] > '04:00:00':
         df['Time_Category'] == 'Morning'
    else:
        df['Time_Category'] == 'Midnight'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `pd.cut`

```
s = pd.cut(df.Time, pd.to_timedelta(['04:00:00','12:00:00','17:00:00','23:59:59']),
          labels=['Morning','Afternoon','Evening']).astype(str).replace('nan','Midnight')
Out[43]: 
0    Afternoon
1      Evening
2     Midnight
Name: Time, dtype: object
df['Time_category'] = s
```

Comment: I got a 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.time' '

Comment: @Luc df.Time=pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

Comment: not working for me - ValueError: bins must be of datetime64 dtype